# While reviewing "The Late answers" should we compare it to other answers?

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits, late-answers

When I was reviewing the Late answers on Stack Overflow I "failed" on the [following audit question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/20682288):

[image: Audit question]

Which happened to be just a copy and paste of the of the [accepted and well-received answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197151/facebook-open-graph-cant-download-could-not-retrieve-data-from-url/20197599#20197599)

[image: Accepted answer]

**My question:**

During the reviewing, the late answers should we open the question on a new page and compare it to the other answers?

If this is really needed, why doesn't Stack Overflow show other answers along with the question to make it easier to review?

Comment: [Review first post / late answers: show other answers as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174445/review-first-post-late-answers-show-other-answers-as-well), [While reviewing “The Late answers” should we compare it to other answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373088/while-reviewing-the-late-answers-should-we-compare-it-to-other-answers)

Comment: Related: [Late Answers audits should show comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228932)